# changing Arrow Color for users

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

iam a Django BackEnd Developer and i have created a Blog
i just want to know how to color slected Arrow after user Vote for specific Post and save it

this is Arrow Html:

```html
<a href="{% url 'home:post-vote-up' id=posts.id %}">
  <i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>
</a>
<p class="lead">{{posts.votes}}</p>
<a href="{% url 'home:post-vote-down' id=posts.id %}"
  <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>  
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an ID and an onclick function for the element you want to select with JS and after you selected it, change it's color:

```js
function arrowClickUp() {
  document.getElementById("arrowUp").style.color = "red";
}

function arrowClickDown() {
  document.getElementById("arrowDown").style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<a href="{% url 'home:post-vote-up' id=posts.id %}">
  <i onclick="arrowClickUp()" id="arrowUp" class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>
 </a>
 <p class="lead">{{posts.votes}}</p>
<a href="{% url 'home:post-vote-down' id=posts.id %}">
  <i onclick="arrowClickDown()" id="arrowDown" class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i> 
</a>
```

Note: you should link the font library you using to you snippet, because you'll see nothing

Comment: but dude everytime i refresh the page the color goes off